# The simpliest AngularJS code not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my web site I am developing a simple AngularJS functionality - firing alert from a module controller. This is my code:

app1.js:

```
(function() {
    var app1 = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app1.controller('MyController', function() {
        alert('Hey');
    });
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular</title>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app1.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
    {{5 + 3}}
</body>
</html>
```

There result in my browser should be:

> 8

with an alert firing with a message "Hey", right? And what I get is only this in my browser:

> {{5 + 3}}

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Obviously Angular was not bootstraped correctly. Any errors in your console? Try removing (function() { ? Check your angular script path as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You app and controller initialization code was never called, you need to do this:

```
(function() {
    var app1 = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app1.controller('MyController', function() {
        alert('Hey');
    });
})(); // <=== Change is here
```

Explanation:

```
(function() { /*code*/});
```

will create an anonymous function, but won't *call* the function. To call it, you need to add `()` at the end before the `;`:

```
(function() { /*code*/})();
// Here ----------------^
```

More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: @ Rasalom: I've taken the liberty of editing to show what I meant.